# How would you find the profit maximising level of output of these 2 products?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, finance, numerical-optimization

Suppose a company produces two products A and B which have demand functions
\begin{gather*}
D_{A}=30-P_{A} \\
D_{B}=25-P_{B}
\end{gather*}
With $P_{A}$ and $P_{B}$ being their prices.
If the combined cost function is 
\begin{gather*}
C=x^{2}+2xy+y^{2}+10
\end{gather*}
where $x$ denotes number of units of product A and $y$ denotes number of units of product B, what is the profit-maximizing output?

My attempt at this so far, has been as follows:

Profit = Revenue - Costs

Where Revenue is given by $P_{A}x+P_{B}y = x(30-D_{A})+y(25-D_{B})$

Thus, we have
\begin{gather*}
Profit = P = x(30-D_{A})+y(25-D_{B})-(x^{2}+2xy+y^{2}+10) \\
P=30x-D_{A}x-x^{2}+25y-D_{B}y-y^{2}-2xy-10
\end{gather*}

So this is the equation that we need to maximise. To do this, I assume I must differentiate the expression for $P$ (implicitly) to find its critical points. Is this correct?
If so, how would I differentiate the left hand side of the equation? Would it just be $0$?

Comment: The sensible domain for the profit function is the set $\{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^{2}|x\geq 0, y\geq 0\}$.  In the interior of this quadrant (the points away from the axes), yes, you need to find the critical points of the function.  Since $P$ is given explicitly in terms of $x,y$, all you need to do is search for the zeroes of the gradient $\nabla P$ of $P$ (you just differentiate the right hand side).  But since we include the positive $x$- and $y$-rays, we also need to search for the local maxima of $P$ along the axes, which you can do by finding the local maxima of $P(0,y)$ and $P(x,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit differentiation necessary. First you have to consider that $D_A$ and $D_B$ are the quantity units x and y respectively. The profit function becomes:

$P(x,y)=30x-x^2-x^{2}+25y-y^2-y^{2}-2xy-10$

$=30x-2x^2+25y-2y^2-2xy-10$

*Differenting w.r.t $x$ and $y$*

$\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}=30-4x-2y=0$

$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=25-4y-2x=0$

Solving this little equation system leads to the solution for $x$ and $y$. Because of the negative coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ this stationary point will be the maximum.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm also trying to work out the profit maximising price and the maximum profit. To work out the profit maximising price, I assume you would substitute $x=30-P_{x}$ and $y=25-P_{y}$ into the equation for profit and then solve it for $P_{x}$ and $P_{y}$. Is this correct? Also, what should I do to find the maximum profit?

Comment: Yes and then you insert the expressions for$ P_x$ and $P_y$ into the revenue function: $R(x,y)=P_x\cdot x+P_y\cdot y$ . And the profit function ist $P(x,y)=R(x,y)-C(x,y)$ To find the maximum profit you just solve the little eqaution system I´ve posted. $30-4x-2y=0 \Rightarrow 2y=30-4x$ Multipliying both sides by $(-2):-4y=8x-60$. Inserting the expression for $-4y$ into the second equation: $25+\color{blue}{8x-60}-2x=0 \Rightarrow 6x=35$. I think you can take it from here.